# Geocoder not work in real device

Tags: android, gps, geocode

```
private void test(){
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);
        String ret = "";
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(-6.267563,
                    106.934707, 1);
            if (addresses != null) {
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder(
                        "Address:\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress
                            .append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append(
                                    "\n");
                }
                ret = strReturnedAddress.toString();
            } else {
                ret = "No Address returned!";
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            ret = "Can't get Address!";
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, ret, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I try run this code, and work in my emulator 
( setting ) >>  http://prntscr.com/6n4tk7
And i install in my device, it's get output "Can't get Address". My phone is jelly bean, and GPS and internet is on. 
what's the problem? And sorry for my bad english.

UPDATE :

I try to run on other emulator, and work only in emulator target Google APIs.

> > > http://prntscr.com/6n4tk7

Comment: Geocoder not always works in some devies.,It fails for me when device was connected in 3g data while it worked fine when device was connected to wifi.

Comment: Hi, @KarthikaPB . My pc connected to wifi and work. My device too, but not work.

Comment: try another device I have micromax,samsung devices here it works fine with geocoding but panasonic does not works on the same so try another device.